# What is the significance of "Onathappan" during Onam?

Tags: vishnu, festivals

During the festival of Onam, we worship `onathappan`. Could someone explain what this `onathappan` signifies? If it is Mahabali, then why are there three, along with one for Thrikkakarappan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from this [link](http://www.vaikhari.org/thrikkakara.html) explains in detail.

> First, Thrikkakara Temple is one of the few temples in India dedicated
>   to Lord Vamana the fifth incarnation of Lord Vishnu. It is situated in
>   Thrikkakara, 2 kilometers east of Idapally near Cochi. The name
>   Thrikkakkara means the holy place where Lord placed His foot.
>   Thiru-kal-kari later became Thrikkakara
>
> The legend is closely linked with the story of Mahabali and Lord
>   Vishnu's Vamana or Trivikrama incarnation. Mahabali was an efficient
>   and popular Asura king. His kingdom stretched the earth, the patala
>   (the underground), and was threatening the skies. The gods (suras)
>   grew worried of Mahabali's rule and popularity. Vishnu, in his avatar
>   as Vamana, asked Mahabali for a piece of land only three paces wide.
>   Bali, ever the generous king, granted this wish, whereupon Vamana grew
>   to an immense size and covered the heavens with one step and the earth
>   with another. There was no space left for Vamana to measure his third
>   pace. "Where is my third foot of space?" asked Vamana. Tricked by this
>   deceit, but as one who would never go back on his promises. Mahabali
>   offered his own head for Vamana to place his third step. These events
>   were happened at this place. As he was pushed down into Suthala, King
>   Bali made a last request. He requested that he be allowed to visit
>   Kerala once in a year to ensure that his people were still happy, well
>   fed and content. Lord Vishnu was pleased to grant Mahabali his wish.
>   Mahabali comes to visit his people and his land during Onam. This is
>   the legend behind the Onam festival.

Hence, Onathappan is a representation of Mahabali visiting once a year, as a way of showing mutual care for the people and the land he once ruled.

Comment: There are controversies over the place of rule by Mahabali. The yearly visit of Kerala by Mahabali is a controversial story as nobody has solid evidences over his ruling in Kerala. Onam was started as an agricultural festiva, but now most people believe the story mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I see. Can you point to link(s) that offer(s) explanation contradicting the answer?

Comment: For now two examples for stating it as a controversy. According to stories, Parasurama created  Kerala from the Sea by throwing his axe into it. But according to Dashavathara, Vamana avatar was happened before Parasurama avatar. Then how can Mahabali rule Kerala even before it existed? According to Srimad Bhagavata, Mahabali did yaga on the banks of Narmada river which is far from the state of Kerala.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing of axe into the sea is just an allegory. Parasurama fought the land with Axe, from malayars(mountain people) and thirayyars(coastal people) and donated it to the brahmins who later settled as namboothris in kerala.He donated the land to brahmins in order to clean the sin of killing Kshatriyas. Before Parasurama avatar(6th avatar), it was the Vamana avatar(5th avatar). Vamana punished Mahabali Chakravarthy by sending him to Suthala. But made him the ruler of Suthala loka. Yes,Mahabali did yagna on Narmada banks. He was a not a king, but Chakravarthy who is 10 times powerful and superior than a king. His ruling area was vast, having Kerala as his Capital !